# How to delete the # from the URL when linking in react or vanilla js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linker, href

I'm developing a website where I have a navbar at the top, and when an option is selected, the screen goes to the part of the page that is linked with the ID. My question is, once that I press the option, the URL shows the # + the option selected. How can I remove the # and leave just the word, or if is it's an option to delete both. IM NOT USING REACT-ROUTER-DOM

*WHAT HAPPENS: [www.mywebsite.com/#aboutus](http://www.mywebsite.com/#aboutus)*

*WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN: [www.mywebsite.com/aboutus](http://www.mywebsite.com/aboutus) or just [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)*

**NAVBAR**

```
<div className="main-navbar">
    <a href="#home">home</a>
    <a href="#aboutus">about</a>
    <a href="#contact">contact</a>
</div>
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
<div id="aboutus">
  //CONTENT
< /div>
```

Comment: Are you able to remove the '#' sign from the anchor tags?

Comment: Removing the `#` will have server side consequences. If you reload the page with the revised url the server doesn't know that path. Servers don't see the hash part (`#xxxx`)

Comment: if i do that it doesn't go the part of the page that i want to, it just refresh the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the # can't be removed because the # is specifying the element which you want to focus on, other than the # you can use Element.scrollIntoView()
and make a click event that will scroll to the element without #

```
document.getElementById("yourid").scrollIntoView();
```

check this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) for more info